TypeScript doesn't infer the return type of a function properly
I have a function that returns an API store where all the backend APIs are located. This has a reason, let's keep it aside.
loginCreate function:
loginCreate: (data: AuthenticationRequest, params: RequestParams = {}) =>
  this.request<AuthenticationResponse, IReason[]>({
    path: `/login`,
    method: "POST",
    body: data,
    secure: true,
    type: ContentType.Json,
    format: "json",
    ...params,
  })

This function is stored in the Api class within my library project.
In the lib project I'm exporting the Api class as AccountApi like this -
import * as AccountApi from "./lib/api.account";

export { AccountApi };

In my actual application I'm instantiating the AccountApi class like this -
import { AccountApi } from "@central/api";

export default function accountApiStore(authToken?: string) {
  if (authToken) {
    return new AccountApi.Api({
      baseUrl: process.env.ACCOUNT_HOST,
      securityWorker: () => ({
        headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${authToken}` }
      })
    });
  } else {
    return new AccountApi.Api({
      baseUrl: process.env.ACCOUNT_HOST
    });
  }
}

Then I'm using the Api like this -
const signing = await accountApiStore()
    .login.loginCreate({
      username,
      password,
    })
    .catch((e) => e);

  if (!signing.ok) {
    const res = await signing.json();
    return json(
      {
        errors: { username: res[0]?.message ?? "Invalid username or password" },
      },
      { status: 401 },
    );
  }

Now, the issue with this usage is that I do not have the proper type assigned to the signing variable.

What I want is that, the return type AccountApi.HttpResponse<AccountApi.AuthenticationResponse, AccountApi.IReason[]> of the createLogin() method should be assigned to the signing variable.

Can anyone help me with that. Is there something that I'm missing?

You'll need to show us what .login, .loginCreate and in particular .request are doing

Do you know what .catch((e) => e) does? It returns a promise that resolves with e which is typically of type any

.request is sending the request to the backend with the data that we're calling it with.
.login is used to access the property (as object) called login inside the Api class.
.loginCreate is the method inside the login object which will eventually call the .request method.
The Api class is a dump of a swagger.json file of our backend, if you can relate swagger-typescript-api -p url/to/swagger.json -o ./lib -n api.account.ts

If there is an error then .catch((e) => e) will catch that error and store it in the response. Later that response will be stored in the signing variable.
I'm not sure about the any type coming from this catching part or not. I'll check it by refactoring...

@ShabbirHossain Yes but what is the type of .request(…)?!

The problem is...

.catch((e) => e);


This returns a successful Promise that resolves with the value of e.
Given Promise rejections in TypeScript reject with an any value, you've told your code that signing will receive whatever type request() returns OR any.
From interface Promise<T> in lib.es5.d.ts...

/**
 * Attaches a callback for only the rejection of the Promise.
 * @param onrejected The callback to execute when the Promise is rejected.
 * @returns A Promise for the completion of the callback.
 */
catch<TResult = never>(onrejected?: ((reason: any) => TResult | PromiseLike<TResult>) | undefined | null): Promise<T | TResult>;


Taking the lowest common type, the result can only be any.
The correct way to handle this would be to not mix await with .then() / .catch()
try {
  const signing = await accountApiStore().login.loginCreate({
    username,
    password,
  });

  if (!signing.ok) {
    const res = await signing.json();
    return json(
      {
        errors: { username: res[0]?.message ?? 'Invalid username or password' },
      },
      { status: 401 },
    );
  }
} catch (e) {
  console.error(e);
  // throw new Error('Login failed'), etc
}


Here's a super simple example demonstrating the problem clearly
// hover over v1 to see the type is "any"
const v1 = await Promise.resolve('value').catch((e) => e);
console.log(v1);

try {
  // hover over v2 to see the type is "string"
  const v2 = await Promise.resolve('value'); 
  console.log(v2);
} catch (e) {
  console.error(e);
}

TypeScript Playground

I tried to mention you in my post's update section but couldn't. But anyways, your suggestion from the small comment lead me to the correct path. And this explanation is cherry on top. Thank you very much brother...
